# Read files from external disk through command line after login?

Tags: raspbian, python, permissions

I wrote a pygame program that acts like a mp3 player on Raspberry Pi, and I want it to run from startup, which I accomplished by adding `python Music.pyw` to the bottom of `.bashrc`

This works fine, that is, if I have already booted desktop mode (`startx`)
But when it is a fresh boot, it tells me permission is denied to my flash drive with all of the songs!

What can I do, to.. grant myself permission?

Sidenotes:
    -I am very new to linux/raspberry pi
    -I am running Raspbian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your "external disk" (or "flash drive") isn't being mounted.  When you run your desktop (I guess LXDE?) then it looks for drives and mounts them for you.

To confirm this, look at the path which your python program is trying to use, and from the console do an `ls` command on this path.  The error message will tell you whether it's a permissions problem or a "doesn't exist" problem.

What you probably need to do is edit your `fstab` file so that your drive is automatically mounted at boot time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the device manager UDEV to execute your script when, and only when your external usb disk is detected and mounted. You just have to add a rule the udev rule directory `/etc/udev/rules.d/`. To do that you can put your rule in a custom file that you can name `30-my-custom.rules`

Follow more detailed instructions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/74593/linux-ubuntu-run-script-upon-usb-mount).